# How Were These Coefficients in a Polynomial Approximation for Sine Determined?

Tags: java, c, math, trigonometry, taylor-series

Background: I'm writing some geometry software in Java. I need the precision offered by Java's BigDecimal class. Since BigDecimal doesn't have support for trig functions, I thought I'd take a look at how Java implements the standard Math library methods and write my own version with BigDecimal support.

Reading [this JavaDoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StrictMath.html), I learned that Java uses algorithms "from the well-known network library netlib as the package "Freely Distributable Math Library," fdlibm. These algorithms, which are written in the C programming language, are then to be understood as executed with all floating-point operations following the rules of Java floating-point arithmetic."

**My Question**: I looked up fblibm's sin function, [k_sin.c](http://www.netlib.org/fdlibm/k_sin.c), and it looks like they use a Taylor series of order 13 to approximate sine (edit - njuffa commented that fdlibm uses a minimax polynomial approximation). The code defines the coefficients of the polynomial as S1 through S6. I decided to check the values of these coefficients, and found that S6 is only correct to one significant digit! I would expect it to be 1/(13!), which Windows Calculator and [Google Calc](http://www.google.com/?gws_rd=ssl#q=1%2F(13!)) tell me is 1.6059044...e-10, not 1.58969099521155010221e-10 (which is the value for S6 in the code). Even S5 differs in the fifth digit from 1/(11!). Can someone explain this discrepancy? *Specifically, how are those coefficients (S1 through S6) determined?*

```
/* @(#)k_sin.c 1.3 95/01/18 */
/*
 * ====================================================
 * Copyright (C) 1993 by Sun Microsystems, Inc. All rights reserved.
 *
 * Developed at SunSoft, a Sun Microsystems, Inc. business.
 * Permission to use, copy, modify, and distribute this
 * software is freely granted, provided that this notice 
 * is preserved.
 * ====================================================
 */

/* __kernel_sin( x, y, iy)
 * kernel sin function on [-pi/4, pi/4], pi/4 ~ 0.7854
 * Input x is assumed to be bounded by ~pi/4 in magnitude.
 * Input y is the tail of x.
 * Input iy indicates whether y is 0. (if iy=0, y assume to be 0). 
 *
 * Algorithm
 *  1. Since sin(-x) = -sin(x), we need only to consider positive x. 
 *  2. if x < 2^-27 (hx<0x3e400000 0), return x with inexact if x!=0.
 *  3. sin(x) is approximated by a polynomial of degree 13 on
 *     [0,pi/4]
 *                   3            13
 *      sin(x) ~ x + S1*x + ... + S6*x
 *     where
 *  
 *  |sin(x)         2     4     6     8     10     12  |     -58
 *  |----- - (1+S1*x +S2*x +S3*x +S4*x +S5*x  +S6*x   )| <= 2
 *  |  x                               | 
 * 
 *  4. sin(x+y) = sin(x) + sin'(x')*y
 *          ~ sin(x) + (1-x*x/2)*y
 *     For better accuracy, let 
 *           3      2      2      2      2
 *      r = x *(S2+x *(S3+x *(S4+x *(S5+x *S6))))
 *     then                   3    2
 *      sin(x) = x + (S1*x + (x *(r-y/2)+y))
 */

#include "fdlibm.h"

#ifdef __STDC__
static const double 
#else
static double 
#endif
half =  5.00000000000000000000e-01, /* 0x3FE00000, 0x00000000 */
S1  = -1.66666666666666324348e-01, /* 0xBFC55555, 0x55555549 */
S2  =  8.33333333332248946124e-03, /* 0x3F811111, 0x1110F8A6 */
S3  = -1.98412698298579493134e-04, /* 0xBF2A01A0, 0x19C161D5 */
S4  =  2.75573137070700676789e-06, /* 0x3EC71DE3, 0x57B1FE7D */
S5  = -2.50507602534068634195e-08, /* 0xBE5AE5E6, 0x8A2B9CEB */
S6  =  1.58969099521155010221e-10; /* 0x3DE5D93A, 0x5ACFD57C */

#ifdef __STDC__
    double __kernel_sin(double x, double y, int iy)
#else
    double __kernel_sin(x, y, iy)
    double x,y; int iy;     /* iy=0 if y is zero */
#endif
{
    double z,r,v;
    int ix;
    ix = __HI(x)&0x7fffffff;    /* high word of x */
    if(ix<0x3e400000)           /* |x| < 2**-27 */
       {if((int)x==0) return x;}        /* generate inexact */
    z   =  x*x;
    v   =  z*x;
    r   =  S2+z*(S3+z*(S4+z*(S5+z*S6)));
    if(iy==0) return x+v*(S1+z*r);
    else      return x-((z*(half*y-v*r)-y)-v*S1);
}
```

Comment: freefall83 1+. This is one heck of a question, I'm interested to see the answer.

Comment: It is possible this is (say) a Chebyshev polynomial approximation rather than a Taylor polynomial.

Comment: I can't explain the discrepancy you pointed out. But do note that S6 is multiplied with x^13, which is at most about .04 (i.e., order 10^-2). S6 itself is order 10^-10. This means that the contribution of the S6 term is order 10^-12. This is really starting to push the precision of a double. Doesn't justify the discrepancy of course, but it does give you an idea of the severity of the issue.

Comment: arrow in the dark: That's the nearest possible decimal that can be represented exactly in floating point.

Comment: @AkshayArora a double should have somewhere around 15-17 digits of precision, I think. A discrepancy in the second decimal is kind of bizarre.

Comment: @JSQuareD Agreed. This is a good question. Excited to see the answer.

Comment: @freefall83 fdlibm uses a minimax polynomial approximation, which provides smaller error than a simple Taylor approximation. See Wikipedia entry for minimax approximation.

Comment: @njuffa Thanks for your response. So I guess the answer is that S1 - S6 are _not_ actually coefficients to the Taylor polynomial, but instead are the coefficients of a minimax polynomial? Minimax polynomials are not something that I'm familiar with. I thought the Wikipedia entry was sparse with details on the _how_ of things. I'd really like to know how the values of S1 through S6 were arrived at. Maybe the details are not trivial. In any case, thanks for mentioning this. If you have any other references, please post!

Comment: @freefall83 Yes, S1-S6 are coefficients of a minimax polynomial approximation. Wikipedia tells you what a minimax approximation is: it provides the *smallest maximum error* of any polynomial approximation of same degree. It also points you to the most common method of computing minimax polynomial approximations: the Remez algorithm. Various tools such as Mathematica or Maple have built-in facilities for minimax approximation. I would suggest taking a look at the free tool [Sollya](http://sollya.gforge.inria.fr/), in particular its `fpminimax` function.

Answer (score 6):

We can use trig identities to get everything down to 0≤x≤π/4, and then need a way to approximate sin x on that interval.  On 0≤x≤2<sup>-27</sup>, we can just stick with sin x≈x (which the Taylor polynomial would also give, within the tolerance of a double).

The reason for not using a Taylor polynomial is in step 3 of the algorithm's comment.  The Taylor polynomial gives (provable) accuracy near zero at the expense of less accuracy as you get away from zero.  By the time you get to π/4, the 13th order Taylor polynomial (divided by x) differs from (sin x)/x by 3e-14.  This is far worse than fblibm’s error of 2<sup>-58</sup>.  In order to get that accurate with a Taylor polynomial, you’d need to go until (π/4)<sup>n-1</sup>/n! < 2<sup>-58</sup>, which takes another 2 or 3 terms.

So why does fblibm settle for an accuracy of 2<sup>-58</sup>?  Because that’s past the tolerance of a double (which only has 52 bits in its mantissa).

In your case though, you’re wanting arbitrarily many bits of sin x.  To use fblibm’s approach, you’d need to recalculate the coefficients whenever your desired accuracy changes.  Your best approach seems to be to stick with the Taylor polynomial at 0, since it’s very easily computable, and take terms until (π/4)<sup>n-1</sup>/n! meets your desired accuracy.

njuffa had a useful idea of using identities to further restrict your domain.  For example, `sin(x) = 3*sin(x/3) - 4*sin^3(x/3)`.  Using this would let you restrict your domain to 0≤x≤π/12.  And you could use it twice to restrict your domain to 0≤x≤π/36.  This would make it so that your Taylor expansion would have your desired accuracy much more quickly.  And instead of trying to get an arbitrarily accurate value of π for (π/4)<sup>n-1</sup>/n!, I’d recommend rounding π up to 4 and going until 1/n! meets your desired accuracy (or 3<sup>-n</sup>/n! or 9<sup>-n</sup>/n! if you’ve used the trig identity once or twice).

Comment: For arbitrary-precision computation, it may make sense to further restrict the input domain of the sine function approximation by the use of a multiple-angle formula such as sin 5x = 5 sin x - 20 sin³ x + 16 sin⁵ x.

Comment: Minor: [binary64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format#IEEE_754_double-precision_binary_floating-point_format:_binary64) has 53 (not 52) bits in its "mantissa" (52 explicitly stored. 1 implied)

Comment: @Teepeemm Note that I specifically proposed using an identity based on sin 5x to avoid rounding errors in the division during argument reduction when a decimal format is used (such as BigDecimal).

Comment: @njuffa I'm not at all familiar with the internals of BigDecimal.  Does it store things in base 10, so that dividing by 5 is ok?  Or in binary, so that dividing by 5 leads to an infinite decimal?

Comment: @Teepeemm Good question. I do not use Java and may have been misled by the name `BigDecimal` into assuming that it stores data base 10**n, for some suitable value of *n*. I do not know the implementation details. I guess the safest way for minimizing rounding error without knowledge of the actual encoding of `BigDecimal` may be to chose a multiple-angle formula that uses 2x, 4x, etc (which would work for binary and decimal storage), but as far as I am aware these then require the computation of both sine and cosine. May be less desirable from a performance perspective despite good ILP.

Comment: I just checked the [source code](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/math/BigDecimal.java) for `BigDecimal` and it seems in fact to be decimal, as the name suggests. So a reduction formula based on sin 5x should provide superior accuracy.